# Angular JS - Configure External Web tools

Tags: visual-studio, angular

I try to refer the instruction in AngularJS (with Visual Studio 2015) Portal(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html#!#prereq1) under 
Prerequisite: Node.js

[image]

Which one should I choose? Just **click "Next" button** only OR **choose "npm package manager"** ?
Prerequisite: Configure External Web tools.
**On the right, move the $(PATH) entry above the $(DevEnvDir) entries.** This tells Visual Studio to use the external tools (such as npm) found in the global path before using its own version of the external tools.

I have no idea  to about "move the $(PATH) entry above the $(DevEnvDir) entries" ? It mean I have to remove the $(PATH) ? Got any sample to do that? have screenshot is more better.

Comment: _Which one should I choose?_.....You can go for default installation. That won't harm.

Comment: @Jai thanks but for the Prerequisite: Configure External Web tools how we perform "move the $(PATH) entry above the $(DevEnvDir) entries. "?

Comment: check this in the envrionment variables PATH.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea to about "move the $(PATH) entry above the $(DevEnvDir) entries" ?

It's talking about VS configuration, rather than Node. Go to `VS: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools`, you will see a list on the right, probably containing `$(PATH)` and `$(DevEnvDir)`. Both of them are system macros used for 3rd-party tools search.

This piece of instruction asks you to install Node first and to make sure your VS apps find it first, instead of other existing instances.